# chartjs how to customize x axis value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, plotly

I am working on chartjs lib and stuck in to customize the line graph x axis.

[image]

In the above graph my starting index value is 0 but I wanted to start it from 50 like in the below graph

[image]

And for that my code is.

```
    ticks: {
      suggestedMax: 140,
      suggestedMin: -140,
      stepSize: 10,
      beginAtZero: false,
      autoSkip: false,
}
```